# How to access webservice / asmx file in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, web-services, asmx, file-handling

How to access webservice / asmx file in wordpress?

Comment: its FTP and its a security risk since people might actually access your config.php

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has no relationship with Web Service. You can freely access the sub-folder as you wish (same as other websites).

However in most cases, directory listing is prohibited in most servers, as it will cause security issues.

Comment: ok let's change the question " how to access asmx file in wordpress " .. 

thanks for the quick response though..

Comment: Still unclear. How do you want to access asmx file ? via PHP SOAP ?

Comment: yeh it would be SOAP.. 

but I want it accessible by url.. like "www.mywordpresssite.com/ws/mywebservice.asmx"..

I have done this in joomla but I don't how it's done in wordpress since I don't know where to place my files in the first place..

Comment: It's too broad. Which page do you want to call the Web Service? Hint: the WordPress theme files are at: `wp-contents/themes/{THEME_NAME}`

Comment: that's the point.. i don't wanna call it on any page.. i want it directly accessed using URL.. 

I think asmx could be ran using some sort of wordpress redirection functions but i'm trying to avoid using it since it will require me to create another page template which, btw, has already flooded my site's backend and it's messy..

Comment: it's weird that PHP & ASMX store in same server. Re-think.

Comment: I just found out that folders/files outside 'wp-admin', 'wp-content' and 'wp-includes' can be directly accessed.. :D

Comment: Yes, as said in my question.